# PHP URL Japanese

Tags: php, url-rewriting

I am having a problem with the URL Japanese.

when I copy and paste address URL here, it looks

```
http://test.alwaysriding.co.uk/%E3%83%80%E3%82%A6%E3%83%B3%E3%82%BF%E3%82%A6%E3%83%B3-%E3%82%B5%E3%82%A4%E3%82%AF%E3%83%AB%E3%82%A6%E3%82%A7%E3%82%A2-180/
```

so I have to enter www.test.com/[japanese text here] so that you can imagine.

This is my code:

```
$_request_uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$request_uri = urldecode($_request_uri);
```

when I view source, it looks:

```
string(46) "/ãƒ€ã‚¦ãƒ³ã‚¿ã‚¦ãƒ³-ã‚µã‚¤ã‚¯ãƒ«ã‚¦ã‚§ã‚¢-180/"
```

What is wrong with the code?

Comment: I would strongly advise against using non-ASCII characters in URLs...

Comment: Kolink,Thanks for replied however I dont know how to do what you said. Can you let me know more about that ?